# How to convert .tga files to .png?

Tags: mac, png, tga

I wish to convert TGA files (from Steam) to something more suitable, like PNG. I can't find any converters or workflows, I don't mind which it is. For Snow Leopard.

edit: Are there any free fronts to ImageMagick that are either graphical, or capable of taking a whole folder at once? Also, what does -depth 24 do? It didn't work for me, is there meant to be a different word or a =?

Comment: I know this doesn't really answer the question, but you can find an online one [here](http://www.converthub.com/tgatopng.php).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would recommend the `convert` command from [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php).  It can convert almost any graphics format into any other.

```
$ convert image1.tga image1.png
```

Answer (score 4):

For those of you who are looking to convert more than one file you can use ImageMagick's built-in command "mogrify". First cd to the directory with the files you want to convert then run the following command:

```
$ mogrify -path [output-folder] -format [desired-output-format] *.[desired-input-format]
```

For example:

```
$ mogrify -path output-folder/ -format png *.tga
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as finding an application for Mac is a little hard, you can use online services like these:

- http://www.pictureresize.org/online-images-converter.html
- http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-png

There's tons of these online. Those are just a few. Plus they're free! (as in beer)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a graphical user interface, you can use [GraphicConverter](http://www.lemkesoft.com/content/188/graphicconverter.html). It also allow batch conversion.